# PHP String to time Error

Tags: php, strtotime

I've been using string to time in my website to format the date stamps held in a database and up until now the method I'm using has been fine up to this point. Here is the code:

```
$memberdate = $member['date'];
$memberdate = date('jS F Y', strtotime($memberdate));
```

The initial $membersate value is *1381742596* - The output value is *1st January 1970*

Does anyone know a reason why this would be working for all other pages/scripts but not now?

Comment: because 2nd date parameter has to be an integer (so $memberdate would be enough). strtotime() requires a string, like "2013-11-07" or "+1 day"

Comment: `var_dump($member['date']);`

Comment: Ah yes, thanks @Asenar - I just had a look at my other date stamps and they're in 20131107 format so that's why it works for those - Thanks again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strtotime()` is used, when you are converting ie. "2013-11-07 16:29:30" to its integer value.

But you already have it as unix_timestamp (integer value), so you dont need to use `strttotime()`.

```
$memberdate = date('jS F Y', $member['date']);
```